# Does rsync or duplicity really write files on mounted storage?

Tags: filesystems, mount, rsync, synchronization

I've got an external storage, which is mounted as cifs:

```
$ mount
...
//somespace/backup on /mnt/backup type cifs (rw)
...
```

And I have write some file:

```
$ rsync /home/user/files /mnt/backup
```

or

```
$ duplicity --encrypt-key="GPGKEY" /home/user/files /mnt/backup/duplicity
```

Should I call `sync` after these operations, or files are really have written to `/mnt/backup` folder after `rsync` or `duplicity` execution??

And is it depends on mount fs type?

Comment: I don't think it is assured that your files will be synced to the hard drive, at least not for `rsync`. If you want to be sure the backup is already there, you should call `sync` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you mounted your drive with the `sync` option, your files are not guaranteed to be written to disk immediately, only eventually. However they are guaranteed to be written at the moment you `umount` your drive, that's why that operation is mandatory and you should not unplug your drive without unmounting it first.

So either mount your drive with the `sync` option (`mount -o sync ...`) or manually sync data to disk with the `sync` command.

On the other hand, the `sync` mount option will significantly alter your write throughput (especially with rotating disks) since the system will write data immediately, without reordering the writes nor combining several writes of the same block into one single write. And be aware that with certain devices (especially low-end memory cards) and certain FS that frequently write data at the same place (e.g. journaling FS), your device may wear out prematurely.

The latter paragraph is of course not your concern with a network filesystem like CIFS.